# Why is an IF statement affecting whether an object is defined?

Tags: javascript, properties, undefined, ecmascript-5

I am modifying some JavaScript for a game mod which returns information for use by HTML.

Originally this code looked as follows:

```
  model.foreign_intelligence = ko.computed(function () {
    var primary = model.selection.system().star.ai()
    var commanders = []
    if (primary) {
      commanders.push(intelligence(primary))
      if (primary.minions) {
        commanders = commanders.concat(primary.minions.map(intelligence))
      }
      if (primary.foes) {
        commanders = commanders.concat(primary.foes.map(intelligence))
      }
    }
    return commanders
  })
```

For HTML layout reasons I wanted to move primary.foes into a separate block. After some fiddling I ended up with the following:

```
  model.ffa_opponents = ko.computed(function () {
    var primary = model.selection.system().star.ai()
    var commanders = []
    if (primary) {
      if (primary.foes) {
        commanders = primary.foes.map(intelligence)
      }
    }
    return commanders
  })
```

I am stumped by something though, which is that if I remove the `if (primary)` check around `if (primary.foes)`, then <s>primary.foes is coming back as undefined</s> I get an "*`Cannot read property 'foes' of undefined`*" exception. I don't understand why an IF check is able to affect the existence of an object.

Unfortunately my knowledge of JavaScript is very limited and I've been mainly beating problems through brute force. I was hoping someone might explain, and then perhaps suggest how this code should better be structured. It strikes me that this IF nesting is unnecessary, but it's the only way I've made it work so far.

Comment: Can you say more about what value `primary` has in your scenario?

Comment: you might be calling that function somewhere again when primary is available and hence that will allow to skip and run when available

Comment: *"...then `primary.foes` is coming back as undefined"*: I guess you misinterpret the error message. It probably says that `primary` is undefined. In JS `undefined` is a "falsy" value, so when you do `if (primary)` and `primary` is undefined, it will not execute the `if` block.

Comment: well is something else getting called later where it fills it in? Hard to know from the limited amount of code provided.

Comment: Post the exact error message.

Comment: @epascarello It's a local variable, nothing else can fill it in.

Comment: If @trincot is right, the error message would be `Cannot read property 'foes' of undefined`. Is that what you're seeing?

Comment: Apologies, the error is ```Cannot read property 'foes' of undefined```. Primary looks like this: ```Object {commander: "/pa/units/commanders/quad_tokamaktech/quad_tokamaktech.json", econ_rate: 0.65, color: Array[2], team: 0, name: "Servant Tokamaktech"…}```. Foes is an array within that object. Foes does not always exist within Primary.

Comment: @Barmar I am not sure how `model.selection.system().star.ai()` would be a local variable. Sounds like this method is called before something else is being called.

Comment: @trincot Now that it's confirmed please make that comment an answer

Comment: Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you write *"...then primary.foes is coming back as undefined"*, you confirmed in comments that the actual error message is:

> Cannot read property 'foes' of undefined

...which means that `primary` itself is undefined.

In JavaScript `undefined` is a "falsy" value, so when you do `if (primary)` and `primary` is undefined, it will not execute the if block. So it *does* make sense to have that `if`.

Answer (score 1):

This is language specific to check object for null and undefined.
But this not works to check empty arrays. To check array for empty use length check:

You can simply you code:

```
model.ffa_opponents = ko.computed(function () {
    var primary = model.selection.system().star.ai();
    var commanders = [];
    if (primary && primary.foes) {
       commanders = primary.foes.map(intelligence);
    }

    return commanders;   
})
```

Comment: `primary.foes.langth` ? That check is redundant as if the length is zero then the *map* will be skipped anyway, and if `primary.foes` is undefined will throw a type error.

Comment: Typo in your condition.

Comment: If `primary.foes` is undefined, you can't get the `length` property.

Comment: This does not answer the question. @Quitch asks why it happens, not how to work around it.

Comment: @Barmar quick calculation is still works in JavaScript

Comment: Do you mean short-circuit evaluation of `&&`? It should be `if (primary && primary.foes && primary.foes.length !== 0)` to prevent errors.

Comment: @Barmar yes. Right you are.

Comment: The *length* check is still redundant.

Comment: Yes, it is redundant. Thank you.

Comment: *"But this not works [sic] with arrays"*: This is not true and contradicts with the code you provide.

Comment: It first message variant I told about using && to check empty array. It checks for null or undefined not for empty array, isn't it?